# IE9 js load order and JQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

This seems like an easy problem to solve, but it's kickin my ass.

The following simple example produces an error in IE9. I've used IE9's developer page to monitor network loading and it looks like IE is loading and executing the body's script before the included javascript is loaded/evaluated.

I've tried all the various tricks found via searching for answers including adding `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` and `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE8"/>`

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Demo of IE suckiness</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' 
      src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
This works in every browser but not IE9. IE gives the error:
<pre>
Line: 9
Error: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object
</pre>

<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("Must not be IE");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a work-around. Move the ready script to `<body onload="ready()">`, but I can't believe this is broken for IE9, I must be doing something wrong and just can't see it.

Comment: Why do you use "defer" ? $(document).ready means that it will be executed when the document is loaded.

Comment: can you verify the jquery library is being downloaded?  Maybe http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js is being blocked for some reason.

Comment: I verified it was being downloaded. The problem was it was not being loaded before the page's script was being run.

The "defer" was a mad attempt to get it to NOT load first. I just wasn't making sense.

The solution below was to reset all of my IE settings. I must have changed security settings or something? It just doesn't make sense that IE would download, but then not load JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I fixed it by  [**resetting all my IE9 settings**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737/en-us).
I think by cranking up security or privacy it can break jquery loading from an external page.

Comment: Wow. OK. That worked! How did you know to even try it? I've been spending hours on it. Naturally, I was running it on my local server (localhost) and tried loading the jquery from a localhost path, but nothing was working.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I could find out, IE9 only fires $.load() when the whole document (including all images & related stuff) has been loaded. Terrible but true! My workaround for this:

```
            var docReady = {
                actions:new Array(),
                flag:0,
                time:0,
                period:10,
                trigger:function() {this.flag=1},
                checkHandle:0,
                check:function() {
                    this.time+=this.period;
                    if(this.flag) {
                        clearInterval(this.checkHandle);
                        for(i in this.actions) {this.actions[i]();}
                    }
                },
                watch:function() {
                    this.checkHandle = setInterval(function() {docReady.check();},this.period);
                },
                action:function(f) {
                    this.actions.push(f);
                }

            };

            docReady.watch();
```

A dirty one indeed but it's working; now whenever you see fit, you can call docReady.trigger() and you should do it at least at the end of the page. Also, you can call it as body onload. It's guaranteed that the functions you've added with docReady.action() will only run once: when the first trigger() happens.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to leave out `defer="defer"`?

Comment: If this is an answer, why is it a question? :D

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I did try that combination.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by NOT using Google's hosted jQuery and hosting it locally.

Comment: Greetings James. Welcome to Stackoverflow. You can provide answers to the question that has been already answered. No problem with that. The spirit is to share the different experience between the community members. Take some time to read the FAQ.