# Strange javascript execution order IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to load a remote script with some function and the execute it inline in IE9.
However I encountered an error message that my function was undefined.

What it boils down to is that IE9 (and lower, it seems) executes the script in opposite the order I would expect. I made a simplified example, which still yields the same bug for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="multibanner_rev04_tmp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">alert('nr.2');</script>
```

The script has a longer path I edited out for readability, it only has an alert in it and nothing else.

the alert 'nr.2' executes before the one in multibanner_rev04_tmp.js in IE9
I've tried this on multiple computers with IE9, to make sure it wasn't the same problem as this: [IE9 js load order and JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988405/ie9-js-load-order-and-jquery)

Problem seems to be consistent. Also tried this on IE10, which does execute the alerts in the expected order.

I don't really get what's going on here, any ideas?

Comment: What's the content of `multibanner_rev04_tmp.js`? The question doesn't make a lot of sense without it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's just an alert, like so: alert('nr.1');

Comment: @ jesper: Again: Show the script. If I have a script file that consists of just `alert("file");` and use it exactly as you've used yours above (followed by an inline script with `alert("inline");`), with IE9, I do not get the behavior you describe. I get the `"file"` alert, then the `"inline"` alert. So if you're going to claim that it does, you have to show a complete example. It's likely to relate to something you haven't shown.

Comment: @ jesper: Also cannot replicate with IE8, or with IE6 (I don't have IE7 handy). (You did say "and lower, it seems"). My test case: http://pastie.org/8462672 (Note that the `type` attribute serves no purpose whatsoever in the above and could be removed, but I wanted to replicate your test case to the extent I could.)

Comment: @ jesper: Also cannot replicate without a `doctype` (in case it was some weird quirks thing specifically around `alert`): http://pastie.org/8462681

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

That's my doctype in this case. had some other script there before I switched to alerts for testing.

Comment: My script is identical to your pastie, only difference is the alert message.
I've replicated the problem in IE9 and IE8 (no IE7 at hand and don't really need support for IE6). The script is injected onto my page using yet antother script (through an ad-server), so that might be a problem worth checking out. Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: @ jesper: *"The script is injected onto my page using yet antother script (through an ad-server)..."* Oh for crying out loud. **That was important information to put in the question.** Please don't waste people's time by leaving out obviously-relevant information. The question is completely misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment on the question:

> The script is injected onto my page using yet antother script (through an ad-server), so that might be a problem worth checking out.

That's a **completely different thing** from what you actually have in your question. What you have in your question shows script tags in the markup; *injecting* a script with JavaScript is completely different.

There are two ways the ad script could be adding the script to the page:

1. Using `document.write` during the main page parsing to write out a script tag. You've said your page is XHTML strict. Using `document.write` to output markup to the page during the main parsing is invalid in XHTML, full stop. You cannot do it. If it works at all, the behavior is unspecified and you shouldn't rely on it.

   If you want to use `document.write` during the main page parse, you have to stop using XHTML. At that point, the scripts will be evaluated in the order the parser sees them (regardless of how they got put in the parser's input stream, from the markup or via `document.write`).
2. By creating a `script` element (`document.createElement('script')`) and then appending that to the DOM. When you do this, the script is evaluated as soon as it's available. There is no order. It's just like using the [`async` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async) in the markup (except that it's much more cross-browser reliable).

   If that's how the script is added, you cannot rely on the order. If you control the script being added in this way, you could have that script check for whatever the other script provides and use `setTimeout` to defer its execution until that other thing shows up. If you don't, you'll have to delay the addition of the script element until you're ready for it.

Comment: You are right, of course, I should have thought about that. Sorry if my question was misleading. Curiously, what I'm trying to do does work in Chrome, Firefox and IE10. I'm only ran into trouble with IE9/IE8.

Answer (score -1):

(My first ever post to stackoverflow...)

Stating the obvious...the first script tag requires the browser to load a separate script file
whereas the second script tag has the javascript inline (in the HTML).

Assuming that you have "alert('nr.1');" at the top of your multibanner_rev04_tmp.js then it appears as though IE9 is executing the inline code first even though it
appears later in the HTML, which is incorrect behaviour according to this:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#script

> If neither attribute [async or defer] is present, then the script is
>   fetched and  executed immediately, before the user agent continues
>   parsing the page.

However, using IE10 with "IE9 standards" document mode set (I don't have IE9), I can't reproduce the behaviour you are seeing, which would sort of point towards a bug in IE9 itself or a specific version of IE9? I wonder what happens if you add a defer="defer" attribute to your second script tag ? (Just for diagnosis, because it's not strictly legal according to the standard without a "src" attribute.)

Comment: I do have "alert('nr.1');" in multibanner_rev_tmp.js (in fact, that's all it contains right now).

Tried to add defer, this caused IE9 to not run the inline script at all. Seems to be a difference in document mode compared to the real browser sometimes, I've experienced this with IE8 as well.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to stackoverflow! I guess you might have been here for a while but as a poster at least :)

Comment: Just an aloof observer so far. I registered just be be able to +1 useful posts more than anything but don't even have enough reputation for that so far. Thanks for the welcome :-)

Comment: @Lqueryvg: *"Stating the obvious...the first script tag requires the browser to load a separate script file whereas the second script tag has the javascript inline (in the HTML)."* Yes, but the spec (and long-standing practice) is **quite** clear that unless you use the `async` or `defer` attributes, script elements in the HTML must be *evaluated* in order.

Comment: @Lqueryvg: Looks like your answer has been downvoted. Don't take that the wrong way. This particular answer is incorrect, but you're clearly a smart informed person and I hope you're kind enough to keep trying to help people out.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, isn't that exactly what I said in my post? I quoted the same from the spec.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - thanks for the encouragement BTW - it means a lot!

Comment: @Lqueryvg: Right, but your answer says what should be happening. It doesn't explain why the OP isn't getting that result, so it doesn't answer the question.